# Image Button not displaying, On click is working

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am working on Android studio, with an xml that displays a comment like in Facebook. My issue is that one of the buttons, the comment_more_options button, is not showing up in my actual device run, on the emulator provided with Android Studio, but does show up in my xml preview. However, when I click where the button should be, in the app run, the menu that is attached to it displays properly. What am I doing wrong?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/comment_profile_picture"
            android:layout_width="40sp"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.26"
            app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comment_displayName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom|left"
                android:text="Display Name"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Menu" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comment_handle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:text="Handle" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/comment_more_options"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="@string/enter_comment"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**#.** Add attribute `android:weightSum="1.76"` to child `LinearLayout`.

**#.** Instead of using `app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"`, use attribute `android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1.76">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/comment_profile_picture"
            android:layout_width="40sp"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.26"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comment_displayName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="bottom|left"
                android:text="Display Name"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Menu" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comment_handle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="top|left"
                android:text="Handle" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/comment_more_options"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.50"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:text="Enter Comment"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**You can also use `RelativeLayout`. Here is an example:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/comment_profile_picture"
            android:layout_width="40sp"
            android:layout_height="40sp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/comment_more_options"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_camera" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_middle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/comment_profile_picture"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/comment_more_options"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comment_displayName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Display Name"
                android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Menu" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/comment_handle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:text="Handle" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comment_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="Enter Comment"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

> android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"

And make sure that your icon's color is not same as the background's.